# How can I dynamically assign the same id to a list of rows upon creation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, coldfusion

I'm creating a new table to define a new relationship between classes and class blocks that are nothing but groups of classes.

Here's the workflow:

A user has a training system and needs to be able to create blocks of classes. 
These classes come from a stock list of courses, and the classes are run at different times of the year, at different locations. Some classes can be individual, others are in what we call Class Blocks or Course Blocks.

The system needs a redesign because the old schema they had didn't account for duplicates and had a lot of bad data.

So here's what I'm developing now -

ClassBlocks - A reference table with three fields: A ClassBlockID, the Block Name, and an isActive field. This is a small table with the ClassBlock Names, as these names are to be repeatedly used.

Classes - A table with all the classes that either have occurred or will occur. It has its own ClassID, name of the class, an id that corresponds with the course the class is based on, and the class start and end date

Courses - A reference table that has all the courses available.

ClassBlockAssociation - New Table I'm designing to better define the relationship between classes and blocks of classes. Some classes are individual, others are in blocks. What this table does is handle the case when they're in blocks. It's fields would have A BlockAssociation ID as the primary key, the classID, and the ClassBlockID.

In the sql-server database, I have this table that I'll call Blocks with the following fields:

```
    BlockID (PK)
    ClassID (FK with class table)
    CourseID (FK with Course Table)
    CourseBlockID (FK with CourseBlock Table, table which has course block names) 
    BlockAssociationID (Field that serve as an identifier for class blocks)
```

In coldfusion I have a cfquery that creates a new ClassBlock like this.

For a list of classes, I'll have code like this:

```
   <cfloop index="i" list="#ClassesList#">
       <cfquery name="insertClassBlocks">
        INSERT INTO ClassBlocks(CourseBlockID, ClassID, CourseID)
        VALUES(CourseBlockID, #i#, CourseID)
      </cfquery>
   </cfloop>
```

That's what I currently do to take a created block and add them to this table. Class blocks could have the same name, but where they'd differ is the start and end dates. When these blocks are created, I need to give them an ID that allows me easily retrieve all the classes in the block.

So currently, when I'm testing this and creating the blocks, I'll get a table that looks like this.

```
BlockID  |  ClassID | CourseID | CourseBlockID

1        |    356   |    208       |     1

2        |    357   |    294       |     1

3        |    294   |    256       |     3

4        |    308   |    206       |     3
```

This works for most of what I need to do, the problem is that this table can have multiple blocks with the same CourseBlockID. I could have two blocks with different classes either at the same time, or different time, and they need another unique identifier.

In the example above, I would need some unique block identifier that maps to rows 1 and 2, and another one that maps to rows 3 and 4. This unique identifier needs to be created and inserted for the records at or after the time of insertion into this blocks table. I'm calling it a BlockAssociationID as it is a key used to associate classes to blocks.

I'm not sure of the best method of creating this unique identifier for course blocks.

Comment: First, using a `cfloop` around a `cfquery` will beat up your database. You'll make a new connection on each loop. You'd be better to try to insert in a single `cfquery` with a batch of records built up.

Comment: Second, be very careful of SQL Injection. Check `#i#`.

Comment: Finally, what is `BlockAssociationID`? How are you using this ID? Can you describe your workflow one step back? Or better yet, the final output of how these tables will interact. I'm not sure what you're trying to get to here.

Comment: @Shawn I updated the question with a diagram of the table and also some more description on what I need it to do.

Comment: The naming conventions are a little confusing, which raises questions about whether the tables and relationships are structured correctly. For example, what is the difference between a "Block" and "CourseBlock"? Why is a CourseBlock different than a block of classes? Perhaps instead of describing the tables in terms of their PK/FK, could you explain what each of the entities represent?

Comment: Can you use SQL Fiddle or dbFiddle to create a basic workflow of what you're trying to do? What else goes into these tables that make them necessary? Is `CourseBlock` a reference table that links `Courses` and `Blocks`? What is the workflow you're trying to accomplish here. Usually, if someone can't look at a plain-text description of your schema and the names and tell what is happening, it might mean that the schema needs to be restructured.

Comment: @Ageax  - CourseBlock is a reference table that only has the list of Course Block Names. 

It's a very small table that may have about 10 or so course block names to use. 

Classes have a many to one relationship with courses. One course could be referenced in a variety of classes. The differentiating point is in the dates of the class, and the location of the class. This is specified in the class table.

Comment: @OscarMcCullough - Thanks. Yes I understood the keys and relationships from the OP, but .. that doesn't really explain what a "CourseBlock" is or represents - in plain english ;-) Unfortunately, entity names are often semi-arbitrary terms, so the meaning doesn't always translate well outside the application business rules. Maybe take Shawn's suggestion and create a sample workflow using http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ or https://dbfiddle.uk/ ? Showing some demo values, instead of only numeric id's, might help shed some light on things.

Comment: After re-reading the updated post, something still seems off about the relationships.  Typically, a "Course" could have many classes (one to many relationship). The parent CourseID would be stored in the "Class" table. So it doesn't really make sense to include it again in the other junction tables. Also, if a "Block" just an arbitrary grouping of courses or classes, then a separate table - with a unique key- would make more sense. Then use the unique key in a "ClassBlock" or "CourseBlock" table, which would eliminate the need for a tie breaker column, i.e. BlockAssociationID altogether.

Comment: .. and thanks for taking the time to try to provide a thorough explanation. If you have time do post a fiddle,  as "a picture is worth a thousand words" ;-)